# How to correctly handle errors when writing data to firebase using set in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to handle errors when a person is trying to write data to firestore through my flutter app using the following piece of ccode, but it doesn't work, where is the problem with it?

```
Future createTrip({
    required final String from,
    required final String to,
    required final String buscompany,
    required int price,
    required int seats,
    required DateTime date,
    required DateTime arrival,
  }) async {
    final tripDoc = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('trips').doc();
    final trip = Trip(
        id: tripDoc.id,
        buscompany: buscompany,
        from: from,
        seats: seats,
        to: to,
        price: price,
        date: date,
        arrival: arrival);
    final json = trip.toJson();

    await tripDoc.set(json).then((value) {
      //show trip added on dialog
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Alert'),
                content: Text(' Trip from ${trip.from} to ${trip.to} added'),
              ));
      errorMessage = '';
    })
        //show error message
        .catchError((e) {
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = e.toString();
      });
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Alert'),
                content: Text(' Trip not added because $errorMessage'),
              ));
    });
  }
```

I'm using set so that I can write the trip id inside my document, and I wanted to show an alert that trip is added or not if error occurred using an alert dialog, but I keep getting errors as seen in below screenshot. This code is in a material button in my UI.

Here's the code in the button

```
MaterialButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          final buscompany = buscompanycontroller.text;
                          final from = fromcontroller.text;
                          final to = tocontroller.text;
                          final price = pricecontroller.text;
                          final seats = seatscontroller.text;
                          final date = datecontroller.text;
                          final arrival = arrivalcontroller.text;

                          createTrip(
                            from: from,
                            to: to,
                            buscompany: buscompany,
                            price: int.parse(price),
                            seats: int.parse(seats),
                            date: DateTime.parse(date),
                            arrival: DateTime.parse(arrival),
                          );
                        },
                        color: kPrimaryColor,
                        child: const Text(
                          'SUBMIT',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      )
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the button with the onTap method

Comment: Just added it in the edit @Georgina

Comment: Your issue is probably coming from here : `date: DateTime.parse(date)`, `arrival: DateTime.parse(arrival)`. Please include a print out of arrival and date.

Comment: arrival and date are Strings coming from TextEditingControllers @Georgina

Comment: I know they are strings I just need you to print out their values so I can see how I can help you with your situation.

Comment: I added a print function after `createTrip` in material button as `print('$arrival $date');`, here's the values `2022-12-21T04:52:00.000 2022-12-13T04:52:00.000
2022-12-21T04:52:00.000 2022-12-14T04:52:00.000` @Georgina